# Display Entire Dataset,Python

Tags: python, pandas

i wanted to display an output which is in the form of a data frame. I typed the name and displayed it. I wanted to see the first 2000 names and I used:

```
Data[:2000]
```

The output displayed only the first 60 observations followed by dots and a statement 
2000 rows * 5 columns.
how do I display all of the 2000 observations??
Pandas version - 0.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default options are listed here

```
pd.describe_option('display')
```

according to the option descriptions, to change the default print behavior, I guess:

```
pd.set_option('display.height', some_value)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', some_value)
```